# Universal functions for showing date and time in any locale separately

Tags: android, date, time, calendar, locale

I have a problem, I need the universal functions for showing date and time in any locale separately. But I can't find the way to do it without the checking the `calendar.getLocale()`

this function will give the date in US locale

```
static public String getDateFromCalendar(Calendar cal) {

        return String.format("%tD", cal);
    }
```

But if the Locale is russian I have to use istead this: String.format("%td.%tm.%tY", cal);
I don't want to use the conditional operations for every possible locale.
Please help to find the way to do is simplier.

Comment: Is this Java language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean Java, I suggest you to consider the class `java.text.DateFormat`. Background is that every country/locale has its own typical date-time-format. For example:

```
public static String getDateFromCalendar(Calendar cal) {
    // maybe get user-locale via ThreadLocal or via second method parameter
    Locale locale = new Locale("ru", "Ru"); 

    DateFormat dateFormat = 
      DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
    return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

You can adjust the format style by choosing between SHORT, MEDIUM, LONG or FULL. For MEDIUM the output is: `05.04.2014` Compare that with the output for `Locale.US` yielding: `Apr 5, 2014`.

Comment: Ok, but dateFormat object includes the calendar instance and Locale. I'd not wanted doubling of calendar information. Is is a way to use as example the dateFormat.setCalendar(cal) for initializing the object? or something else. I can't find in DateFormat class the non-static functions for outputing the current date or time.

Comment: @Monotype `DateFormat` expects two parameters - style and locale. The style is defined by your use-case-requirements, the locale can be evaluated by user preferences (where ever you get it from). Then your method `getDateFromCalendar(...)` can use given example code to format the method argument of type `Calendar`. My use of `new GregorianCalendar()` was just an example, use your method argument like `dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())` - no doubling required.